# How to save create and save submodel from keras mobilenet?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have create mobilenet v2 model in keras together with lambda function which gives me output from the penultimate layer. How can I save this specific submodel ( I want to convert it with tfjs-converter and use it in tensorflow-js ) ?

```
from keras.applications.mobilenet_v2 import MobileNetV2
model = MobileNetV2(input_shape=None, alpha=0.35, depth_multiplier=1, include_top=True, weights='imagenet', input_tensor=None, pooling=None, classes=1000)
get_3rd_layer_output = K.function([model.layers[0].input],
                                      [model.layers[-2].output])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Keras model instead of a Keras function and save it with the `model.save(filepath)` method:

```
custom_model = keras.models.Model(inputs=model.layers[0].input, 
                                  outputs=model.layers[-2].output)

custom_model.save('model.h5')
```